# can we create a new widget in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, widget

being new to Flutter i've noticed that it offers a lot of widgets to choose from. But my question is : Can we make our own? foe example, Can I make my own kind of button that's not already offered?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you can create your own widget. For example, as you stated above, you can create a custom button using code like the one below.

> The properties that you see inside the `OutlineButton` constructor build the button with a red background color, a circular border-radius of 32px and a text. The is also a `onPressed` function inside there that is executed when you press the button; in the example below after pressing the button you print to the console the statement `I pressed it`.

```
Widget _buildButton(BuildContext context){
    return OutlineButton(
      onPressed: (){
        print('I pressed it');
      },
      color: Colors.red,
      shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(32.0)),
      child: Text('CUSTOM BUTTON'),
    );
  }
```

You can also wrap your button inside a `ButtonTheme` widget, which offers you multiple features, one of them is to scale the button with the sizes you need.

```
Widget _buildButton(BuildContext context){
    return ButtonTheme(
      height: 100,
      minWidth: 100,

      child: OutlineButton(
        onPressed: (){},
        color: Colors.red,
        shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(32.0)),
        child: Text('CUSTOM BUTTON'),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can create custom widgets in flutter. The following code creates custom button as:
[image: Custom Button]

```
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class CustomButton extends StatelessWidget {
  CustomButton({@required this.onPressed});
  final GestureTapCallback onPressed;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return RawMaterialButton(
      fillColor: Colors.green,
      splashColor: Colors.greenAccent,
      child: Padding(
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
        child: Row(
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
          children: const <Widget>[
            Icon(
              Icons.face,
              color: Colors.amber,
            ),
            SizedBox(
              width: 10.0,
            ),
            Text(
              "Tap Me",
              maxLines: 1,
              style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      onPressed: onPressed,
      shape: const StadiumBorder(),
    );
  }
}
```

You can use the CustomButton like this:

```
class _CustomWidgetDemoState extends State<CustomWidgetDemo> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
          children: <Widget>[
            Text("here is a custom button in FLutter"),
            CustomButton(
              onPressed: () {
                print("Tapped Me");
              },
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can create your own widget even with animation using `Flare`

See this tutorial:

https://medium.com/flutter-community/how-to-create-button-animation-with-flare-in-flutter-part3-implement-animation-in-flutter-project-f335f88311c8